# How to create c# mongodb pipeline that includes $redact

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to create a a mongodb aggregate pipeline using the C# driver that includes redact followed by a project.  I have tried several ways shown below but in each case only the first stage of the pipeline is executed. The AppendStage does not appear to append the next stage.  So how does one have a redact followed by a project using the C# mongodb driver. Note that the fluent interface does not directly support redact but another post showed using the code below to do it which works for the first stage.

I am using 2.4.3 version of the C# driver and mongodb version 3.4.4

```
string redactJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"redactTest.json");
string projectJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"projectTest.json");

var collection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Forecasts");

var redact = BsonDocument.Parse(redactJson);
var project = BsonDocument.Parse(projectJson);


var aggregatonPipeline = collection.Aggregate();
aggregatonPipeline.AppendStage<BsonDocument>(redact);
aggregatonPipeline.AppendStage<BsonDocument>(project);

var list = aggregatonPipeline.ToList();
```

or similar code like this

```
var pipeline = collection.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(redact);
pipeline.AppendStage<BsonDocument>(project);
var list = pipeline.ToList();
```

Where my aggregate json looks like these

redactTest.json:

```
{
    $redact: {
       $cond: {
         if: {
             $gt: [{ $size: { "$setIntersection": [ "$tags", ["STLW", "G"]]}}, 0]
         },
         then: "$$DESCEND",
         else: "$$PRUNE"
      }
   }
}
```

projectTest.json

```
{
  "$project":
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "title": 1,
    "year": 1,
    "subsections.subtitle": 1,
    "subsections.content":  1 
  }
}
```

And the source document is

```
{
  _id: 1,
  title: "123 Department Report",
  tags: [ "G", "STLW" ],
  year: 2014,
  subsections: [
    {
      subtitle: "Section 1: Overview",
      tags: [ "SI", "G" ],
      content:  "Section 1: This is the content of section 1."
    },
    {
      subtitle: "Section 2: Analysis",
      tags: [ "STLW" ],
      content: "Section 2: This is the content of section 2."
    },
    {
      subtitle: "Section 3: Budgeting",
      tags: [ "TK" ],
      content: {
      text: "Section 3: This is the content of section3.",
       tags: [ "HCS" ]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collection.Aggregate()` exposes the fluent aggregation interface and appends the stages to the pipeline via method chaining.

Something like

```
var pipeline= collection.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(redact).AppendStage<BsonDocument>(project);
var list = pipeline.ToList();
```

Your usage overwrites the previous stages when add one stage at a time.

Comment: This works. My attempt to prove each stage and then append them was not a good idea.